# ANT: XML resolver not found in XSLT Task using Saxon

Tags: xslt, ant, saxon

I'm trying to create an ANT script that will execute a stylesheet against all Dita files in a folder using Saxon-HE 10.6 on Windows.  I keep running into an error saying the XML Resolver cannot be found though.

```
<xslt style="transform.xsl" basedir="${basedir}" destdir="${destdir}" extension=".dita" processor="trax">
  <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl" />
  <classpath>
     <pathelement path="${resolver.path}"/>
     <pathelement path="${saxon.path}" />
  </classpath>
  <xmlcatalog>
    <catalogpath path="${catalog.path}" />
  </xmlcatalog>
</xslt>`
```

When I run the target, I get the following error:

`Warning: XML resolver not found; external catalogs will be ignored`

Both the saxon and resolver JARs referenced by *saxon.path* and *resolver.path* are in the same folder.

Comment: What version of Saxon are you using, and on what platform?

Can you show us everything your classpath?

Comment: @Norm Saxon-HE 10.6 and on Windows.  And I'm not sure how to check my classpath.

Comment: I believe that the `xmlcatalog` element in the ant task is interpreted by ant, and used to set a URIResolver in Saxon; the error/warning message comes from ant, not from Saxon. Unless you can provide evidence to the contrary, it looks to me like `${resolver.path}` doesn't contain the catalog resolver.

Comment: The `${resolver.path}` points to the resolver.jar file I downloaded from the Xerces2 Java Binary distribution.  I've tried a relative path and an absolute path and both don't work

Comment: @MichaelKay I should add that both the resolver and saxon jar files are in the same folder and so both `${resolver.path}` and `${saxon.path}` have the same root.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help you with this. I've had lots of struggles with Ant and class paths in the past, and the only way I ever solved the problems was by trying lots of different ways of doing things until I found one that worked. It wouldn't surprise me if the xslt/classpath is used only for finding the XSLT processor and not for finding the xml resolver, but that's pure speculation.